# Find html class name using keyword in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been web scraping a website using **BeautifulSoup** who's class names changes ever so slightly every few weeks/months.
Eg.`<div class="ejd3445 text container">` where here the `ejd3445` part changes but `text container` remains and I've been trying to use keywords as `text container` to find the class, but doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You talked about what you've tried so far; can you show the code of that attempt in accordance with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS Selector to select a `class` that ends with `text container`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="ejd3445 text container">'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('div[class$="text container"]'))
```

Output:

```
<div class="ejd3445 text container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
soup.find("div", class_ = lambda value: value and value.endswith("text container"))
```